# Вопрос по JavaScript и HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет. Я написал скрипт для сайта он берет параметр из тега p и каждый час вычитает по 1 и вставляет обратно, но при обновлении страницы счетчик начинается заново. Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

```js
var updateTimer = function() {
  var watch = document.getElementById('watch');
  var count = Number(watch.innerHTML);
  if(count == 0){
   watch.innerHTML = count;
  }
  else{
  watch.innerHTML = count -= 1;
}
};

setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<p><span id="watch">16</span></p>
```

Comment: Если отсчет начинается при первом посещении, то храните в localStorage значение, при повторной загрузке страницы проверяйте есть ли там значение. Если же оно начинает с какого-то конкретного времени, то соответственно используйте разницу между текущим временем и временем начала, и вычитайте из какого-то там значения .... нужно больше вводных.

Comment: Нужно его где-то хранить...обычно важные данные хранятся на сервере в базе данных, Маловажные данные можно хранить в localStorage yf cnhjyt rkbtynf

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно считать время до определённой даты, то можно воспользоваться объектом `Date`.

```js
var summerEnd = new Date(2018,8,1),//Конечная дата(месяцы начинаются с 0 , поэтому сентябрь - восьмой)
    now = new Date(),//текущая дата
    watch = document.getElementById('watch');
function updateTimer() {
  now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 1);//обновляем текущую дату
  watch.innerHTML=((summerEnd - now)/1000).toFixed();
};

setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

```css
#watch{
  display:block;
}
#watch:after{
  content: ' секунд';
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>До конца лета осталось:</span>
  <span id="watch"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы таймер при перезагрузке страницы не сбрасывался, время таймера нужно хранить в `localStorage`.

P.S. При использовании `localStorage` на **StackOverflow** будет писать ошибку.

```js
var watch = document.getElementById('watch');
var count;

if (localStorage['count'] == '0')
    count = 16;
else
    count = localStorage['count'];

watch.innerText = count;

var updateTimer = function () {
    watch.innerText = count;

    if (count > 0) {
        watch.innerText = count -= 1;
        localStorage['count'] = count;
    }
};

setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<p><span id="watch"></span></p>
```